# Combining two z values with same x and y in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, bathymetry, combine, vertical-transformation

I have a point file with elevation values I want to combine with a raster of the same area. I'm assuming I will need to extract points from the raster to store as a .shp file.

Then I need to combine the two sets of z values to create one elevation (in this case i'm adding the one to the other.) Can this be done within ArcMAP 10.3.1?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the **Spatial Analyst** extension you can use the [**Extract Values to Points**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm) tool to add the data from the raster to the point data. You could then use the [field calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_the_Calculate_Field_tool/005s00000029000000/) to add the two values, either in an existing field or in [a new one](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000).